# Which service should contain code for many to many relationship?

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, service, microservices

Let's say that you have a Rack Table and a Bike table. Then you also have a RackBike table that links which bike belongs to which rack and maybe in what order. The structure of the tables is bike and rack tables have id and name column and RackBike has RackId, BikeId, and Order.

To my understanding, in a micro-service world, there is a service for Bike and a service for Rack. Lets call them IBikeService and IRackService.

My question:

Which service would contain the code for Adding/Modifying data to RackBike table? Would it be The Bike Service, the Rack Service or would it be a new service to handle the CRUD of that? And why?

Comment: Consider making your first sentence contain the word "database" somewhere,  it would be a lot clearer. The answer to your question is "it depends". What makes more sense to the consumers of your services? You might even include rack information in the bike service and bike information in the rack service. As to updates and deletes, that's really a "what makes more sense in the problem domain" question. As to the many-to-many part, I can understand a rack having many bikes. What's the other "many" part of the relationship? Maybe bikes and racks are not what I'm imagining

Comment: What is `Order` in `RackBike` table for?

Comment: @ingvar the order in which they are line lined up.